# Possible to have a method on an APIView called from a url

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework is it possible to have a custom method in an `APIView` class be called similar to how `.get()` or `.post()` would be called.

I know it's possible with routers using the `@action()` or `@link()` decorators, I'm trying to figure out if you can do something similar to an `APIView` but have it so I can set the method to whatever url I want.

I've tried decorating the class with `@action()` and `@api_view()` but nothing seems to have worked.

I'm not exactly sure what I should put in the url for an endpoint to actually call the method in the class. Would I use `CartAPIView.clear.as_view()`, `CartAPIView.clear`, or `CartAPIView.clear()`. I've tried different combinations of calls to `CartAPIView` but nothing has worked.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
# views.py
class CartAPIView(APIView):
    @api_view(['POST'])
    def clear(self, request):
        """Clear the users cart."""
        queryset = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)

        queryset.clear_cart()

        serializer = CartSerializer(queryset)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    ....
    url(r'^cart/clear/$', CartAPIView.clear.as_view(), name='clear_cart_api'),
    ....
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of the answers posted here by @knbk and @almalki are both valid approaches to what I was asking. However they are not showing what I actually ended up doing after a few hours or so of looking into it.

I ended up using ViewSets that allowed me to bind the `GET`, `POST`, etc requests to a certain function in a ViewSet class. Usually you would use routers to bind all of the appropriate functions automatically, but I wanted a little more flexibility with how they were bound so I just write them out myself.

```
# views.py
class CartViewSet(ViewSet):
    def clear(self, request):
        """Clear the users cart."""
        queryset = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)

        queryset.clear_cart()

        serializer = CartSerializer(queryset)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

clear_cart_viewset = CartViewSet.as_view({
    'post': 'clear'
})

# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    ....
    url(r'^cart/clear/$', 'clear_cart_viewset', name='clear_cart_api'),
    ....
)
```

Comment: why not using this  on the url like: urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    url(r'^cart/clear/$', CartAPIView.as_view({'post': 'clear'}),name='clear_cart_api'),)

Answer (score 11):

You seem to miss the point of how a class-based view's flow works.

- As a class-based view is a class (obviously), and Django expects an
  unbound function (not attached to a class or instance) as a view, `as_view` handles that by creating an unbound function, and in that function instantiating the class-based
  view.
- `as_view` then calls `self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)`, where `self` is the instantiated object that's just created.
- `dispatch` calls either `self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)` or `self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)`, depending on the request method (or `put`, `patch` or `delete` if those are allowed and used).

There's no room for a custom function like your `clear` function, unless you override one of these methods to call `self.clear(request)`. The equivalent of `@api_view(['POST'])` would be to override the `post(request, *args, **kwargs)` method:

```
# views.py
class CartAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Why would you call this 'queryset'? It's a single object.
        cart = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)
        cart.clear_cart()

        serializer = CartSerializer(cart)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    url(r'^cart/clear/$', CartAPIView.as_view(), name='clear_cart_api'),
)
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems what you are looking for is [Function Based Views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views#function-based-views), where you can decorate a function with `@api_view()`

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['POST'])
def clear(request):
    """Clear the users cart."""
    queryset = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)

    queryset.clear_cart()

    serializer = CartSerializer(queryset)

    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    ....
    url(r'^cart/clear/$', 'clear', name='clear_cart_api'),
    ....
)
```